# Example of a non-arithmetic Veech surface (other than regular polygon)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

I am reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.3318) of Avila and Delecroix of the billiard flow on polygonal surfaces, but I have to get through some basic definitions first.  What is a **non-arithmetic Veech surface**?

> A **Veech surface** is an “exceptionally symmetric” translation surface, in the sense that the Veech group is a (finite co-volume) lattice in $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ (it is easily seen that the Veech group is never co-compact). Simple examples of Veech surfaces
>   are **square-tiled surfaces**, obtained by gluing finitely many copies of the unit square $[0, 1]^2$ along their sides: in this case the Veech group is commensurable with $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$.

These are the kinds of surface they want to rule out (because they will not lead to weak-mixing flows.  The promise is, that as long as you're not scared of decimal error, these problems have an elementary flavor, can be simulated on a computer.  The proofs might not be.

> Veech surfaces that can be derived from square-tiled ones by an affine
>   diffeomorphism are called **arithmetic**. Arithmetic Veech surfaces are branched covers
>   of flat tori, so their directional flows are never topologically weak mixing (they admit a continuous almost periodic factor).

Their example of a non-arithmetic Veech surface is the regular polygon $P_n$ (with opposite sides identified) and or a copy of $P_n$ and its mirror $-P_n$ if $n = 2k+1$.  $S_n = P_n$ or $S_n = P_n \cup (- P_n)$. Then they show two results.  The first one is slightly more refined than the Veech dichotomy because it says these directions are weak-mixing.

> **Thm 2** The geodesic flow in a non-arithmetic Veech surface is weakly mixing
>   in almost every direction. Indeed the Hausdorff dimension of the set of exceptional
>   directions is less than one.

And we get rare examples of weak-mixing dynamical systems (that are not mixing).  The elements of the Veech group are $2\times 2$ matrices living inside a number field $k/\mathbb{Q}$:

> **Thm 3** Let $S$ be a Veech surface with a quadratic trace field (i.e., $r = [k: \mathbb{Q}] = 2$).
>   Then the set of directions for which the directional flow is not even topologically
>   weak mixing has **positive Hausdorff dimension**.

E.g. the regular polygon has trace field $k = \mathbb{Q}[\cos \frac{\pi}{n} ]$  Certainly then, the regular polygons have mysteries yet to unfold, but also I am curious what these positive Hausdorff dimension fractal sets might be.  Another question is if there are Veech surfaces other than than translation surfaces of regular polygons.

Answer (score 2):

Some examples are given in the [2005 paper by Sergey Vasilyev.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504180)